# What does this passage from "Gone With the Wind" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

> The MacIntoshes were Scotch-Irish and Orangemen and, had they possessed all the saintly qualities of the Catholic calendar, this ancestry would have damned them forever in Gerald's eyes.
>   <sub>--from *Gone With the Wind*.</sub>

What does this even mean? (Provided that Gerald was a Catholic himself.)

Comment: That’s “of ***the Catholic calendar***.   (*the, Capital C, calendar with an A).  What part don’t you get?  The ’had they’ qualification? The “Catholic calendar” reference?

Comment: Or was it the reference to Orangemen? (Protestant followers of good King Billy)

Comment: <<<< What does it mean? (Ask a more specific question.)

Answer (score 5):

The MacIntoshes were of Ulster Protestant descent, Gerald of Irish Catholic descent. He would have been prejudiced against them however virtuous they might have been.

Answer (score 3):

In Catholicism (and a number of other branches of Christianity), days of the calendar have traditionally been associated with [specific saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_of_saints). I assume the meaning of the sentence is "Even if the MacIntoshes were as virtuous as all of the saints in the calendar combined, Gerald would still have hated them." This makes more sense to me than ascribing virtuous qualities to the calendar itself, anyway.